# Media Query triggering but elements do not become fluid

Tags: css, media-queries

i am very new to coding so forgive my hopefully simple question.

I am attempting to implement media queries into a website to make it fully 'responsive' and despite following numerous tutorials seem to be having a very basic problem that is no doubt easily solved but a mystery to me due to my inexperience.

The site is built using the 960 grid system, below you can find my media queries css page.

Basically, i can get the media queries to work, in so much as when for example the browser is reduced to 960px or less, the site reacts correctly to the media query css (page becomes  width: 94% and left right margins of 3% ) but as the page continues to be resized, it isn't 'fluid' and doesnt follow the browser edge. It stays at 960px basically, (rather than scaling down) until the next media query (650px) is triggered. Width:auto seems to not be working, as currently the media queries only resize the page when the width is set at percentages or pixels etc for each resolution.

Below is the css and html, again please forgive my presumably novice coding, this is my first site.

Many thanks =]

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {


.container_12 {
width: 94%;
 margin: 0 3% 0 3% ;}

#header {
width: 100%;}

.grid_10 alpha omega {
width:78%;} 

}




@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {


#header {
width: auto;}

.grid_10 alpha omega {
width: auto;}   



}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {



#header {
width: auto;}

.grid_10 alpha omega {
width: auto;}   



}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta    name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>title</title>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media-queries.css" />



</head>
<body>


<div class="container_12" id="container">
<div id="header">
<div class="grid_2 alpha" id="logo">
<h1><a href="/">Home</a></h1></div>

<div class="grid_3  omega" id="navigation">
<ul class="navigation">

<li><a href="/menu1/">menu 1</a></li>

<li><a href="/menu2/">menu 2</a></li>

</ul>
</div>



</div>
<div class="grid_10 alpha omega" id="maincontent">
<h2>hello<a href="/menu1.html" class="h2bold"> world.</a> Lorem Ipsum.</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum.<br>
Lorem Ipsum.</p>


</div>
</div>

</body>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</html>
```

UPDATE: this is my main styles.css, as it seems the problem hasn't been possible to replicate with what i provided.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/***************** Page Styles ***************/

body    {
 background-color:#deeee9;

}

.container_12 {
 background-color:#fefefe;
}


p {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:10px;
line-height: 18px;

}

p a:link {
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;

}

p a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:#fa5e45;

}

p a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:#333;

}

h2 {
padding: 120px 0 13px 0;
font-size:23px;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -1px;
font-weight:100;
}

h3 {
padding: 0 0 3px 0;
font-size:19px;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -1px;
font-weight:100;
}


h2 a:link   {
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold; 
}

h2 a:hover  {
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
color:#fa5e45;
text-decoration:none; 
}


/******************************  Header ********************************/

#header {
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 120px;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed;

}

#logo   {
 text-indent:-9999px;
}

#logo a {
 display: block;
 margin-top:15px;
 border: none;
 background: transparent url(images/logo.png)  no-repeat;
 width: 76px;
 height: 76px;
 border-image: initial;
}



#navigation {
 float:right;
}


.navigation {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 float: right; 
}


.navigation li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline;
 float: left;

}

.navigation a:link {
text-decoration:none;
color: #000000;

}

.navigation a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color: #fa5e45;
}


.navigation a {

margin-top: 30px;
width: 100px;
height: 47px;
border: none;
line-height: 47px;
float: right;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: right;
text-decoration: none;

}


/****************************  Homepage ******************************/





#maincontent p {
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-size:19px;
line-height: 24px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
}

#maincontent p a:link   {
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none; 
font-weight:bold;
}

#maincontent p a:hover  {   
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
color:#fa5e45;
text-decoration:none; 
}


/****************************  menu 1******************************/ 

.workwrapper {
display:block;
clear:both;

}

.workwrapper p{
padding-top:13px;

}

.workurl {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:10px;


}

.workurl a{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:10px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fa5e45;

}

.workurlnull {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:10px;


}

.workurlnull a{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:10px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
color:#999;

}


.workexample {

float:right;
}


.image {
padding-bottom: 40px;
position:relative;
float:right;
text-align:right;
}

/****************************  menu2 ******************************/

.multicolumn1 {

-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:;
}

.aboutimg {
padding-top: 30px;
}

#aboutimg2 {
padding: 30px 4px 0 4px;

}
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue in Chrome. After I hit the `960px` media query, the content (`.container_12`) continues to resize with the browser window (you can put a border on it to easily visualize this). Are there other CSS rules in some of those other files that could be interfering? What browser are you using?

Comment: hey, thanks for giving it a go. I will post my styles.css below if you can mange sifting through it!

Also using Chrome btw

Comment: There is a syntax error in styles.css directly below the rule-set #maincontent p a:link

Comment: oops, it got gobbled while i was paginating the code for the post, updated

Comment: I don't see any conflicts in the styles.css. See the update to my answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine for me in Chrome. I've made a Dabblet of it [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/1959196)